# JavaScript, anyone know whats wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a dark mode toggle for my admin panel with javascript and sometimes when I go to a different page the background will be white for a split second.

Also sometimes the checkbox bugs out a little when I click it multiple times.

Does anyone know whats wrong with it?

Thanks!

```js
var mode = "default";
function swapStyleSheet(){
 var pagestyle = document.getElementById('pagestyle');
 var lightSwitch = document.getElementById('lightSwitch');
 if(mode == "default"){
  pagestyle.setAttribute('href', '../css/dark.css');
     lightSwitch.title = "Turn the lights back on";
  mode = "dark";
 } else {
  pagestyle.setAttribute('href', '../css/light.css');
     lightSwitch.title = "Turn the lights off";
  mode = "default";
 }
}


function save(){
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('lightSwitch');
    localStorage.setItem('lightSwitch', checkbox.checked);
 load();
 //might be fixed by turning load() on (fix this later (glitch makes it so css doesnt load for a sec sometimes and shows white background for split second, (removed buttons(also that when you click save whilst its already activated it will deactive).
}

function load(){    
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lightSwitch'));
    document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked = checked;
  if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked = checked) {
  swapStyleSheet();
 }
}

function restore(){
    location.reload();
    localStorage.clear()
}


load();
```

```html
CSS in header:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="pagestyle" href="../css/light.css?parameter=1">


HTML checkbox to activate/deactivate the darkmode

Dark mode: <input type="checkbox" id="lightSwitch" onclick="save()" onmousedown="save()">
```

Comment: `("lightSwitch").checked = checked` should be `("lightSwitch").checked === checked`. `=` is assignment operator. `==` or `===` are comparison operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `load` function is a bit of a mess:

First, you're setting `#lightSwitch.checked` to equal `checked`, then you're setting it again:

```
function load(){    
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lightSwitch'));
    document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked = checked;
    if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked = checked) {
        swapStyleSheet();
    }
}
```

Simplified, your code does this:

```
var x = true/false;
someproperty = x;
if (someproperty = x)
    doSomething();
```

You probably want to have the assignment *after* the `if` condition, and the `if` shouldn't contain an assignment:

```
function load(){    
    var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lightSwitch'));
    if (document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked !== checked) {
        swapStyleSheet(); // Swap if the value changed
    }
    // assign the changed value
    document.getElementById("lightSwitch").checked = checked; 
}
```

Comment: The first snippet of code actually worked for me, only I still get the white background for a split second when loading a new page. Could it have something to do with my html code?

Comment: Akyx, it appears to work because `if (someproperty = x)` is _always_ true.